# What is the Windows equivalent of getty?

Tags: linux, windows, terminal

In Linux, you can connect a serial terminal to your machine and access it via `/dev/ttySx`. Similarly, you can connect a serial terminal to your Windows machine and acccess it via `COMx`. You can easily write text to the the terminal just by writing to those files. In Windows, you can change the terminal settings via Device Manager. In Linux, you can change them via `stty`. Now suppose that I want to present a login prompt or shell on the terminal. In Linux, I can do this using `getty`. How can I do this in Windows? What is the Windows equivalent of `getty`?

I can redirect the output of `cmd` to the terminal using

```
cmd > COMx
```

but this doesn't do anything with stdin or stderr. I am also wondering if maybe this would be possible using PuTTY, but I don't know how if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible on pure Windows, but you can use WSL1 to do that.
You need WSL version 1 since it can directly use Windows devices with no
virtualization.

The procedure is described in article by Scott Hanselman
[Connect to a device over Serial COM Port on Windows 10 with WSL1 TTY devices with Windows Terminal and minicom](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/connect-to-a-device-over-serial-com-port-on-windows-10-with-wsl1-tty-devices-with-windows-terminal-and-minicom).

Assuming the device is connected to COM4:

- Install `apt install minicom`
- Run for the first time with `sudo minicom -s` to set the defaults,
  for example the default port as `/dev/ttyS4` and the speed to 9600
- If you get "cannon open /dev/ttyS4: Permission denied",
  add your user to the dialout group:
  `sudo gpasswd --add myaccount dialout`
- You can now run minicom on the configured COM4 with:
  `wsl -d DISTRONAME minicom`.

For more details, see the above article.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually did know about this trick, I was wondering if was possible natively. But thank you for letting me know that its not.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say it's impossible in Windows. It seems more like there's just no third-party software already written to do this specific task... (But I mean, even things like dial-up BBSes did exist for Windows.)

Comment: @user1686: No software is the same as impossible, not so?

Comment: @harrymc: Of course not; e.g. originally there was "no software" to make Windows accept SSH connections, but the OS did provide all necessary *building blocks* – making it possible to write the software – so people wrote the software. Windows does allow programs to use serial ports (no difference between 'accept' and 'connect' in serial), and many SSH/Telnet servers exist that run a "detached" cmd.exe for network connections, so the building blocks clearly are there and I'm actually surprised there isn't a getty-equivalent app for inbound serial links yet. Maybe nobody thought it'd be useful?

Comment: @user1686: Maybe, or maybe the architecture of Windows does not easily lend itself to it. In any case, for the poster it is possible with WSL, as Linux does have the required architecture.